# Function stops when (If Statement) ends

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have this function written in a project to locally save some details about the users` accounts

```
public void Forward(string Path,string Name,List<string> AttributeName = null,List<string> AttributeValue = null,string Value = null, int NumberOfNames = 1,bool EndA = true,bool EndB = true)
{
        <codes>
        */if (!AttributeName .Contains(null) || AttributeName .Contains(""))
        {
            var Text1 = AttributeName;
            var Text2 = AttributeValue;
            var BothText = Text1.Zip(Text2, (t1, t2) => new { Word1 = t1, Word2 = t2 });
            foreach (var tt in BothText)
            {
                Lab.SaveAttribute(tt.Word1, tt.Word2);
            }
        }
     **/if (!Value.Contains(null) || Value.Contains(""))
        {
            <codes>
        }
        if (EndA)
        {
            <codes>
        }
        if (EndB)
        {
            <codes>
        }
}
```

The problem is that when the first `If Statement` which marked with `*/` ends, the whole `Function` ends without reaching the second `if Statement` which marked with `**/`.

Note that this only happens when the `AttributeName` is `null` or `""`

why is this happening or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If `AttributeName` is null and you try to access .Contains you should get an exception

Comment: Step through it with your debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `AttributeName` is `null` `AttributeName.Contains(null`) will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Check first if `AttributeName != null` before you access any member functions.

Answer (score 2):

If `AttributeName` is null then your call to `AttributeName.Contains` will throw a `NullReferenceException`. That's why your method is exitting.

You're also passing `null` into `Contains`. If you look at the documentation for [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see that it throws an `ArgumentNullException` if you pass in `null. What are you expecting`Contains`to do when you pass in`null`..?

I'm guessing that somewhere up the call stack you're catching this exception and silently ignoring it! Step through the code with your debugger and you'll see the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Forward(string Path,string Name,List<string> AttributeName = null,List<string> AttributeValue = null,string Value = null, int NumberOfNames = 1,bool EndA = true,bool EndB = true)
{
        <codes>
        */if (!AttributeName.Equals(null) || AttributeName.Equals(""))
        {
            var Text1 = AttributeName;
            var Text2 = AttributeValue;
            var BothText = Text1.Zip(Text2, (t1, t2) => new { Word1 = t1, Word2 = t2 });
            foreach (var tt in BothText)
            {
                Lab.SaveAttribute(tt.Word1, tt.Word2);
            }
        }
     **/if (!Value.Equals(null) || Value.Equals(""))
        {
            <codes>
        }
        if (EndA)
        {
            <codes>
        }
        if (EndB)
        {
            <codes>
        }
}
```